# manage big file in laravel.(how to load?)

Tags: php, laravel, config, laravel-5.1

I've a proxy file, it has 5000 different proxies, currently what I'm doing is, loading all proxies using Configurations(`Laravel Config` I personally thought that it is not a good technique). So please suggest some solution about this issue, another possible solution is to put file in `storage` directory and access it. I'm looking for some solution with good reason. Thanks

PS: I need one random proxy in each request(throughout the application life cycle), So what best way could be to implement it?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally create a Proxy model and store them in a database. This would allow you to have a lot of control over pulling in the proxy you need or editing them programmatically as needed. You can also easily keep track of which proxy was used recently if you want to prevent repeated use of the same ones when pulling them in randomly.

Comment: yeah, that seems pretty clean thing. Thanks :)